# What is the most reliable way to register a clean up when a Python object's ref count reaches zero?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I have a Python client application that communicates with a server. When an object is no longer used on the client side (i.e. ref count reaches zero - using `CPython`), I need to send a message to the server so it could clean the corresponding memory.

From Python's [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) page `__del__` documentation, I know that the mentioned special method is called when the ref count reaches zero, so implementing it to send a message to the server would possibly suffice.

I wanted to ask whether there is a more reliable approach, possibly by using the garbage collector (perhaps by adding a callback using `gc.callbacks`). I'm not sure if all Python objects are handled by it though.

Any help on the most robust way to call clean ups after an object is no longer referenced would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing to know is that the "garbage collection" (`gc`) module in CPython exists *solely* to collect trash caught in reference cycles. In most programs, almost all trash is reclaimed by reference counting alone, and `gc` has nothing to do with it. In fact, I have a number of long-running programs I *know* don't create cyclic trash, and I start them with `gc.disable()`. They can run then for days without leaking memory - refcounting alone (which cannot be disabled) is all they need to reclaim all the significant trash they create.

So, no, thinking about `gc` at all is mostly a red herring here.

`__del__()` is the best hook you have. That's why it exists: to give you a way to do something when CPython learns that an object is trash.

That doesn't mean it's bulletproof, but then nothing can be. For example, if the OS kills your program (via, e.g, `SIGKILL` on Linux), your program ends at once, with no chance to perform any cleanup actions.

An alternative is to use `weakref.finalize(obj, callback, ...)` to register a callback to be invoked when a weakly-referencable object `obj` becomes trash. That has the sometimes-benefit of arranging (by default) for the `atexit` module to run the callback during the normal interpreter shutdown sequence even if the object is still alive then. See the `weakref` module's

"[Comparing finalizers with `__del__()` methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#comparing-finalizers-with-del-methods)"

section for more on that.

Comment: I wished Python documentation on this matter were as clear and concise as your answer - would have saved me a lot of investigation time to put things together. Thanks, Tim! By the way, an honor to hear from you.